# looping through table rows php CSS

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I am looping through an array of results that I have gathered from the database. There are no problems in regards to displaying the data gained from the database. The problem sits within the styling of the data.

I have some CSS for the code below, it styles the first row of data but the rest are just echoed with no styling although they do look as if they sit within the table that is being defined within the php.

```
        $user        = $_SESSION['sess_uid'];
        $conn = new mysqli(localhost, root, DBPASS, DBNAME);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE userID = '" . $conn->real_escape_string($user)."';";
        // Performs the $sql query on the server
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $rows[] = array();

            echo '<table>';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th> Report Name </th>';
            echo '<th> Category Name </th>';
            echo '<th> Sub Category Name </th>';
            echo '<th> Date Uploaded </th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


            echo '<tbody>';
            $rows[] = $row;
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['reportName'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['categoryName'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['subcategoryName'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['reportDateUploaded'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';



        };
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: take your tbody and end table tags out of the loop

Comment: excellent, i didn't realise that they had to sit outside the loop as i thought the tbody had to be run each time a new row was created. thank you very much.

Comment: You *can* leave `tbody` out. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3 Table rows **may** be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements, respectively.

Comment: I love people asking for CSS posting the PHP instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your while statement only contain your tr and td elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `tbody` and `table` tags out of your while loop.

```
 echo '<tbody>';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['reportName'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['categoryName'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['subcategoryName'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['reportDateUploaded'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';     
        }
 echo '</tbody>';
 echo '</table>';
```